# How to select recent errors that were raised in an SQL-Server database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

is there a way to do something like:

select top 100 * from sys.recent_raised_errors order by date

My scenario was that I had an application that executed a stored procedure in the database, and after installing a new trigger on a table,  that procedure had an error raised inside of it, that caused the app to crash. It was obvious to me that the app is crashing due to a DB issue, but I had to debug the app or read its logs to find out what went wrong in the stored procedure.

Comment: If your app logs all errors then what is your problem ? You have all information you need than or not ?

Comment: @GuidoG don't let my personal motivation for the question prevent you from answering it if you know how.

Comment: SQL Server does not throw exceptions, it raises errors. Those errors may be converted to exceptions on the client side. You can try to query the system health event buffer (`FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file(N'system_health*.xel', NULL, NULL, NULL)`, but I don't think this contains run of the mill errors. Even if it did, don't expect to actually get the full context -- it's not much good to get `String or binary data would be truncated` with no context of when, where, how, what parameters, or what your app is doing at the time. There's no substitute for client logging.

Comment: I changed the terminology, thank you for the answer I suspected this might be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try to do below step:**
In Object Explorer, connect to an instance of the SQL Server and then expand that instance.
Find and expand the Management section 
Right-click on SQL Server Logs, select View, and choose View SQL Server Log. 
[image]

[Or you can start profile to tracking the exception](https://nimblegecko.com/how-to-trace-sql-server-database-errors-and-exceptions-with-sql-profiler/)

I just did a testing with SQL Profiler

1. Create a tiger that will get a exception.

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER trig_test
       ON  dbo.T
       AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
   AS 
   BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON;
       SELECT 1/0
   END
   GO
   INSERT INTO dbo.T( remark )VALUES  ( '')
   ```

The following is the message that got from Profiler.
[image]

Comment: I already went through this screen, but it only shows server events, what I'm looking for is a record of errors raised in user session. like when you delete a row that violates integrity. I'm not ruling out that SQL-Server just never saves it.

Comment: @BenGuri Did you try to trace the exception with SQL Profiler?  BTW, you can use fn_trace_gettable load the try log into a table

Comment: the profiler looks useful, but its easier just to read the client logs. I was looking for some kind of a system table that stores this data, but I guess it doesn't exist.